# Closing browser window using a java script inside a PHP code also including session_start();

Tags: javascript, php, session, session-variables

So this is my whole setup :

I'm on a `HTML` page and i'm opening a `POST` request using `JS` inside the same `HTML` page and i'm opening it in a new window like this :

```
<script>
    function Download() {
        form = document.createElement('form');
        form.setAttribute('method', 'POST');
        form.setAttribute('action', 'test.php?App=AppNameHere');
        form.setAttribute('target', 'NewWindow');
        myvar = document.createElement('input');
        myvar.setAttribute('name', 'terms');
        myvar.setAttribute('value', '');
        form.appendChild(myvar);
        document.body.appendChild(form);
        window.open('test.html', 'NewWindow', 'scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=100,width=500,resizable=no,toolbar=no,status=no');
        form.submit(); 
    }
</script>
```

Now inside `test.php` i'm downloading an app referring to the `GET` request for the App var in the `URL`, also the `POST` request works just fine, but after start downloading the file i need to close the window, so i used :

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.close();</script>";
```

Now i tested it and it worked closing the window just fine, **but now here is my problem**... inside the `test.php` file i'm also using sessions (`session_start();`) and when i do use that line (`session_start();`) the java script code for closing the window does not work any more!!, i'v tried commenting all the code but keeping `session_start();` and i really found out that it's what preventing the window from closing, which is very weird, they are not related at all, or this is what i think at least, here is my `test.php` file :

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if($_SESSION["TEMP"] == "Yes"){
        if(isset($_GET['App'])){
            $fileName = $_GET['App'] . " - Setup.exe";
            if(basename($_GET['App']) == $_GET['App']){
                $path = 'download_directory/' . $fileName;
                $size = filesize($path);
                header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                header('Content-Length: ' . $size);
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $fileName);
                header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                header('Expires: 0');
                header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
                header('Pragma: public');
                ob_clean();
                $file = @ fopen($path, 'rb');
                if($file){
                    fpassthru($file);
                    $_SESSION["TEMP"] = "No";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.close();</script>";
?>
```

Downloading the file also worked!

**Can someone please explain to me what's happening and help me go around this because i really need to use sessions?!**

Comment: If `$_SESSION["TEMP"] == "Yes"` and `basename($_GET['App'])` is _not_ equal to `$_GET['App']` or if `$file` is empty, you never close the window. Why not just remove all `else`'s and have one single echo after the first `if`. Then it will _always_ be triggered (and you don't need to repeat it several times).

Comment: This is not the issue, the session TEMP i'm changing the value of it to "Yes" some where else, also the file will start downloading so the line `fpassthru($file);` is triggered and it is going through the if statements!!

Comment: Try and remove the `echo` inside the `if ($file)` block.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I did it, do you mean like that? I've edited my answer, but it didn't work also, it start downloading but now closing the window, when i comment the line (`session_start();`), only then it will close, even if i put the close  line above the start session line!!!!!

Comment: After you output the file you need to have an `exit;`. You can't output js after you've ouputted the file. The browser takes all output (including your echo) as part of the file contents. If you test the ouputted file. Also, set the `$_SESSION["TEMP"] = "No"` before the `fpassthru($file);` Usually, you don't need to close the page manually when you're downloading a file since the browser will do just that, download the file instead of displaying it.

Comment: Your ob_clean() seems unnecessary in this context.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson It **did** work if i didn't open it in a new window!!!! So i set the target to `_blank` and it did work just fine, it opened a new tab started downloading and closed the tab while staying on the same HTML page :) Thanks a lot for try to help.